# jQuery selector updated values get reset when posting form - how to prevent?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, selector, reset

I have an HTML form consisting of checkboxes, select boxes, etc., each with a numeric value for which I'm using jQuery selectors to add up the total, and display the number in a separate div. Here's one:

```
    <label for="OptionalExtra">
        <p><input name="OptionalExtra" type="checkbox" class="calc" value="200" /> Add £200</p>
    </label>
```

Then I use the :checked selector to loop through them all, adding the total up.

```
    $('label').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.calc:checked').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

I can then display this total elsewhere.

**When I submit the form, however, the div holding my calculated value remains there (I do want this), but the value resets (I don't want this - I need it to show the previously calculated value).**

Of course, I know why that happens, but I don't know how to stop it!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So why does it happen then if you know why?

Is it a full submit with input type=submit, or an ajax submit with $.post()?

It sounds like a full submit - which means that your entire page is resent from the server and your calculated div will be put back to it's original value.

Comment: imho this should be more of a comment rather than an answer

Comment: It's a full submit, yes. Are you able to explain to me how to change this? The issue is that I have a already a php module for a CMS I'm using that processes the form, inserts rows into a database, does all the validation, and automatically sends the email to various people upon submitting the form. The module I'm using does have quite powerful control of the flow logic, meaning I can use my own functions at various points of submitting the form. E.g. after validation, before sending email, etc.